# Move files with specific date using Powershell Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, scripting

Need some help with a powershell script. 
I need to move files by a specific last modified date with similar names.
Here is the script I tried running and it just hangs...

```
$SourceFolder = "C:\documents\testing123.txt" 

$targetFolder = "D:\documents"   

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Filter E0100* | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -eq ("08/01/2015") | move-item -destination $targetFolder
```

Comment: I would recommend using `robocopy` instead.

Comment: Should $SourceFolder be a folder, rather than a file?

Comment: Also, comparing LastWriteTime against a date string is not likely to work, as it doesn't include the time. You might consider $_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq "08/01/2015"

Comment: That is a typo the source is a directory not a file. The main issue is that source directory has 1TB of data and hangs any script I run.

Comment: Use `robocopy` instead of trying to script it using PowerShell.

Comment: Not familiar with robocopy, can you please show me an example of command or a link that has a good tutorial. I need to be able filter by name string * and date..

Comment: Would this be the correct syntax for robocopy?                              robocopy C:\documents\  D:documents\  Files123* (* for anything like that filename) /MOV /R:10 /W  Lastly if this is correct, how would I add to look for files with specific last modify date.

Comment: For instructions on using `robocopy`, I recommend reading [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Since, `LastWriteTime` is a `DateTime` the `-ge` in comparing an exact time.  Here is an example that copies using a date range that I believe you desire.

```
$SourceFolder = "C:\documents\testing123.txt" 

$targetFolder = "D:\documents"   
$startTime =[DateTime]"08/01/2015"
$endTime = $startTime.AddDays(1)
Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Filter E0100* | 
     Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -ge $startTime -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $endTime} | 
     Move-Item -destination $targetFolder
```

As others have mentioned, the source folder path seems incorrect.

Here is a `robocopy` version of the script I tried (date, paths, and filter have been changed)

```
$SourceFolder = "D:\test" 

$targetFolder = "D:\test2"   
$startTime =[DateTime]"01/05/2017"
$endTime = $startTime.AddDays(1)
$files = @()
Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Filter * | 
     Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -ge $startTime -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $endTime -and $_.Attributes -ne 'Directory'} | 
     ForEach-Object { $files += $_.Name}

if($files.Count -gt 0)
{
  Write-Verbose "running robocopy $SourceFolder $targetFolder $files /mov" -Verbose
  robocopy $SourceFolder $targetFolder $files /mov
}
```

Comment: Thank you that makes sens, the source is a directory not a file, you are correct. One additional item, if the source destination has a large amount of records, anything I can do to help it not freeze? Some people suggested using robocopy, my only confusion is does robocopy just retrieve the data or does it actually move it as well?

Comment: `/mov` switch on `robocopy` will cause it to move not copy.   `/MAXLAD:n` and `/MINLAD:n` will filter for the maximum and minimum last access date ( I cannot find write date filter).  You could also form the list to copy in PowerShell and pass it to `robocopy`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple two-line PowerShell that will get move your files by date and file type.  You can change the Move-Item to Copy-Item if you do not want to move them.

```
$Now=Get-Date

Get-ChildItem E:\scripts\logs\*.txt | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $Now.AddDays(-7) } | Move-Item -Destination E:\scripts\logs\Archive\7Days
```